# How to set up Sublime Text 3 inverse search in OSX?

Tags: forward-inverse-search, sublime-text

I am using OSX-10.10.5, Sublime Text 3 and Skim. I cannot figure out how to set up the inverse (or forward) search for my system.

I downloaded the "latexmk" package: I downloaded it using the TeX Live Utility and the "latexmk.x86_64-darwin" package was installed. Also, I used both the Skim built-support for Sublime Text and the custom option (see https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/).

The pdf updates with changes in the TeX file, but when I try to do an inverse search nothing happens. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The key combination to go from Skim to TeX editor is hold down the Shift and Apple key and click on a point in the PDF document. Additional setup info for skim with editors is at https://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/wiki/TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization/ you may find there is a history of issues ---**[ Later edit ]** Glad you tracked it down, I have edited my comment to reduce some confusion. As the issue is closed for you and to avoid it listed as still open on this site it would be acceptable for you to accept your own self answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed! I stupidly was using my custom LaTeX build system instead of the built-in one (even though the two have the same path and underlying tex distribution).

edit: A double click might be needed.